# I'm using cakephp 2.x, I need to pass data from a specific controller to a javascript file

Tags: javascript, cakephp

```
$results = $this->Annonce->find('all', 
               array(
                     'conditions' => array('Annonce.name' => $name),
                     'recursive' => -1
      )
);
```

I need to use the value of $results in my javascript file (`/app/webroot/js/filenames.js`)

Comment: you cannot use a php code in file with extension "js"

Answer (score 0):

As you cannot use a php code in `.js` file, what you can do is put the `$results` array in a javascript variable and use that in `.js` file.

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var results= <?php echo json_encode($results); ?>;
</script>
```

Now you can use this variable `"results"` in javascript file